# Notation for equivalence relations

Tags: notation

Equivalence relations typically use the notation $\sim$. But say that I am trying to introduce a relation and prove that it is an equivalence relation. Is it incorrect to use this notation? Does it require that I already know that a relation satisfies the necessary properties? Is the same true for the notation $a \equiv b$?

Comment: Use a notation and define what it means.  The only problem is if the notation has a "usual" meaning that is "close" to what you are defining, and this can be handled by either adjusting your notation (such as using an extra mark like a tick, umlaut, etc.) or else being extra clear each time you use your notation.

Comment: I understand, but I'm not sure what the usual notation here is, because I've seen it done in both ways.

Comment: Youn could use $\sim$, as in this [very nice Brian Scott's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2059183). If you need more examples, just type "Equivalence relation" in the search box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '$\,\sim\,$' symbol is often used to denote "is related to" by whatever relation you are discussing at the time.   The '$\,\equiv\,$' symbol usually denotes "is equivalent to" by whatever equivalence relation you are discussing; and that is most usually a standard form of equivalence.

You *could* use '$\,\equiv\,$' in this case, but more typically we reserve it for relations that are already *known* to be equivalences, rather than those we wish to *prove* are such.